# C# select and scroll to row selected in DataGridView

Tags: c#, select, scroll

I have DataGridView, for now i want to set select row in loop:

- on click button,
- select and scroll to row index 10
- sleep 1s
- select and scroll to row index 12
- sleep 1s
- select and scroll to row index 15

But for now, when click, grid scrolled but not set selected to row.

When all done, grid just set selected and scroll to latest row selected.

Here code when i set selected:

```
dtgList.Rows[dtgList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Selected = false;
dtgList.Rows[dtgList.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Selected = false;

dtgList.Rows[Int32.Parse(tbRow.Text)].Selected = true;
dtgList.Rows[Int32.Parse(tbRow.Text)].Cells[0].Selected = true;
```

Any one help me please!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int selectedIndex = Int32.Parse(tbRow.Text);

if (dtgList.Rows.Count - 1 >= selectedIndex)
{
    dtgList.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = selectedIndex;
    dtgList.Rows[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
    dtgList.Rows[selectedIndex].Cells[0].Selected = true;                    
}
```